# Movefile when string is a variable

Tags: matlab

This is within a forloop aimed at moving multiple files within multiple folders into the 'RawData' directory. I am having issues with using movefile. I would like the file being moved to be a varaible and not a string typed into the command.

Here is a portion of the folder list if needed to better understand:

```
'Data-20141003T091843-1-Eyes Open on Flat Surface-Force.csv'
'Data-20141003T091843-1-Eyes Open on Flat Surface-Results.csv'
'Data-20141003T091923-2-Eyes Closed on Flat Surface-Force.csv'
'Data-20141003T091923-2-Eyes Closed on Flat Surface-Info.csv'
'Data-20141003T091923-2-Eyes Closed on Flat Surface-Results.csv'
'Data-20141003T092208-3-Limits of Stability-Force.csv'
'Data-20141003T092208-3-Limits of Stability-Info.csv'

>>foldername = foldername.name;
directoryname = 'C:\Users\murphy\Documents\MATLAB\RawData\';
folderdirectory = strcat(directoryname,foldername);
cd(folderdirectory);
folderdir = dir('*.csv');
folderList = {folderdir.name}'; %List of Files in folder
for f = 1:length(folderList)      **movefile(folderList(f),'C:\Users\murphy\Documents\MATLAB\RawData')**

end
```

Answer (score 0):

folderList is a cellstr.
In your for loop you need to pass folderList{f} instead of folderList(f).

```
for f = 1:length(folderList)  

    movefile(folderList{f},'C:\Users\murphy\Documents\MATLAB\RawData')

end
```

Comment: I still get the error that I am copying/moving the file onto itself

Comment: Yes. this what your code is doing ;-). You need to adapt. currently source file and destination file are the same.